# Angular4+ ReactiveForms disable and enable a control

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form like below

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <select formControlName='selectList' (selectionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <option value='opt1'>Opt-1</Option>
    <option value='opt2'>Opt-2</Option>
  </select>
  <input type='text' formControlName='inputField'/>
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">Save</button>  
</form>
```

All controls are required. When user select opt1, I want to disable inputField and set value 'something'. If select opt2 enable inputField and set value null.

```
onSelectChange(e){
    if(e==opt1){
        form.controls.inputField.setValue='something';
        form.controls.inputField.disable();
    }else{
        form.controls.inputField.setValue=null;
        form.controls.inputField.enable();
    }
}
```

Enabling control is ok but when I set control disable `inputField.valid=false` and submit button is disabled.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add conditionally "required" on your inputField control.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="inputField" [required]="form.get('selectList').value == 'opt1' ? true : null"/>
```

This way inputField is required only when opt1 is selected.

Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

`setValue` is a method not a property just change to this

```
onSelectChange(e){
    if(e==opt1){
        form.controls.inputField.setValue='something';
        form.controls.inputField.disable();
    }else{
        form.controls.inputField.setValue(null);
        form.controls.inputField.enable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I used setValue like a method not a property but I was write here wrong. The solution is not working. Thanks.